# Unable to import csv to mongo through post method in node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, import

i wanted to create a fronted with a input type file for uploading data to my mongodb collection. I used the below code buts its giving me the following error

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\User\cogazzimport\public\uploads\fcnewimport.csv'
```

My Codes

app.js

```
...
  
var storage = multer.diskStorage({  
    destination:(req,file,cb)=>{  
        cb(null,'./public/uploads');  
    },  
    filename:(req,file,cb)=>{  
        cb(null,file.originalname);  
    }  
});  
  
var uploads = multer({storage:storage});  
  
//init app  
var app = express();  
  
//set the template engine  
app.set('view engine','ejs');  
  
//fetch data from the request  
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));  
  
//static folder  
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,'public')));  
   
  
var temp ; 
let url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/"; 
  
app.post('/',uploads.single('csv'),(req,res)=>{ 

    csvtojson()
  .fromFile(req.file.path)
  .then(csvData => {
    console.log(csvData);

    mongodb.connect(
      url,
      { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
      (err, client) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        client
          .db("coggaz")
          .collection("idata")
          .insertMany(csvData, (err, res) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            console.log(`Inserted: ${res.insertedCount} rows`);
            client.close();
          });
      }
    );
  });

 }); 
//assign port  
var port = process.env.PORT || 3010;  
app.listen(port,()=>console.log('server run at port '+port));
```

index.ejs

```
<form action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
                            <input type="file" name="csv"><br><br>  
                         <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">submit</button></div>     
                        </form>
```

I tried various solutions but still getting the same error. Any solution with a correction code would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
 var storage = multer.diskStorage({  
        destination:(req,file,cb)=>{  
            cb(null,'./public/uploads');  
        },  
        filename:(req,file,cb)=>{  
            cb(null,file.originalname);  
        }  
    });  

var uploads = multer({storage:storage}); 

    router.post('/import_data', uploads.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
        try {
            // importing csv file to database
            const jsonArray = await csv().fromFile(req.file.path);
            const roles = await Role.insertMany(jsonArray)
            await roles.save()
            res.send({msg:"csv data saved successfully"})
            
        } catch (e) {
            res.send(e)
        }
```

use this and change Schema according to your databse name

Comment: not working :( Can u send the full code, maybe im doing wrong anywhere else

Comment: have you created mongoose schema